# Use socket.io in react and node js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am using **reactjs** and **nodejs** for my application. I am calling the api created in nodejs in my react js component. Let's suppose, I have a component **User**. And i am calling api in **componentWillMount** function to get a list of users. So when a new user is added by `add user` component, The change is not reflecting to list of users. So i need to use **socket.io** to make application  real time, so that my list of users can get something is updated in database and its time to render the component again.

Is there anything regarding above?

Comment: You want to addUser and show User RealTime in the same browser? Or like you add user anywhere and you get that user real time?

Comment: Not on same browser. Add user anywhere and get user realtime.

Comment: You should try using componentDidMount for on load data and for dynamic update, I don't think it's good unless you are very sure because it uses a lot of bandwidth and would be hard to manage all the clients which are connected to the server. Would be nice if you're looking for a r&d

Answer (score 1):

You could use Socket.io for updating the users list. Another option is to use server-sent events (for more info on the differences between the two, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5326159/9155551)).

If you choose to use Socket.io, you can emit an event from the client once a new user is added. Once the server receives that event, it broadcasts it to all other connected sockets (using [`socket.broadcast.emit`](https://socket.io/docs/#Broadcasting-messages)). The sockets listen to the users-update event (an example for this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861344/node-js-how-to-make-a-simple-live-page-update/15861401#15861401)), and once they receive it, the client should update the User component and rerender it.

If you choose to use SSE, check out [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-real-time-web-applications-with-server-sent-events/).

Comment: In Server Sent Events there connection is also maintained between server and client.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've revised my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply data from response of api to rendered component, I recommend you will call api on componentDidMount.
It is the great way.
Of course, you can use socket.io

Comment: I am asking, how can i use socket.io with react and nodejs.